# Quickest language to make a little 'Connect to a SSL webpage' script

Tags: python, ruby, perl, bash, ssl

I just need some advice. I already know how to play with bash, ruby, python and perl and I'd like to know: with which of them would it be faster to make a little script that would connect to a website with SSL and login.

I just need to do this script and make a cron job with it. So it must be executable from the console.

Thanks.

NB: If you have any example script, it'd be awesome :)

Comment: There are examples of everything you want to do in each language already on this site.

Comment: this might help: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/HTTPS_request_with_authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the others so can't compare, but in Perl, it's quick and easy with [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod) or LWP

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out!

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Scrubyt](http://scrubyt.org/) if you are familiar with ruby.
an example from http://github.com/scrubber/scrubyt_examples/blob/master/ebay.rb

```
#simple ebay example

require 'rubygems'
require 'scrubyt'

ebay_data = Scrubyt::Extractor.define  do

     fetch 'http://www.ebay.com/'
     fill_textfield 'satitle', 'ipod'
     submit

     record "//table[@class='nol']" do
       name "//td[@class='details']/div/a"
     end
end

puts ebay_data.to_xml
```